# Errors compiling Atlas on windows 10 64bit

Tags: gcc, makefile, cygwin, mingw, atlas

I am trying to build Atlas on windows 10 64bit based on [this page instructions](http://www.pulpgaming.com/2017/01/building-atlas-v3-10-3-for-x86-and-x64-on-windows-10-with-visual-studio/).

Using **Cygwin64** I tried to configure, but I constantly face errors:

#### command:

```
$ ../configure -v 2 -b 64 -Si nocygwin 1 --shared --with-netlib-lapack-tarfile=/cygdrive/c/local/ATLAS/lapack-3.8.0.tar.gz
```

#### Output:

```
OS configured as Win64 (9)

Assembly configured as GAS_WOW64 (9)

Vector ISA Extension configured as  AVXMAC (4,976)

Architecture configured as  Corei4 (32)

Clock rate configured as 3408Mhz
```

...

```
mkdir ARCHS
make -f Make.top startup
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/local/ATLAS/win'
Make.top:1: Make.inc: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'Make.inc'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/local/ATLAS/win'
make: *** [Makefile:542: startup] Error 2
mv: cannot stat 'lib/Makefile': No such file or directory
../configure: line 482: lib/Makefile: No such file or directory
../configure: line 483: lib/Makefile: No such file or directory
../configure: line 484: lib/Makefile: No such file or directory
../configure: line 485: lib/Makefile: No such file or directory
../configure: line 520: lib/Makefile: No such file or directory
../configure: line 521: lib/Makefile: No such file or directory
../configure: line 522: lib/Makefile: No such file or directory
../configure: line 541: lib/Makefile: No such file or directory
DONE configure
```

I don't know exactly why it cannot build **make.inc**.